# Springdoc dynamic server value using YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I'm using springdoc `1.6.9` in a Spring Boot `2.6.7` application and have moved to use a YAML file for the APIs specifications instead of annotations.

I've configured the project to use YAML files following official documentation [12.57. What is a proper way to set up Swagger UI to use provided spec.yml?](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml) and it's working perfectly fine for two Api Groups using the next configuration in `application.yaml` file:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
  swagger-ui:
    urls:
      - name: API 1
        url: /api-spec/api-1.yaml
      - name: API 2
        url: /api-spec/api-2.yaml
```

The only thing I cant figure out is if it's possible to *magically* fill the `server` part of the spec so it point to the environment I'm deploying my app to. With default springdoc settings, server will *automagically* be the URL of the environment. See next screenshot taken using default configuration with annotations:

[image: Server autogenerated by Spring Boot]

Is there a way to configure the YAML file to pick the Server URL from current deployment host like the default configuration?

Comment: You should not update configuration files on the fly depending on the environment. Instead use Spring profiles and override the required property across the profiles.